What does flink store as a state for SlidingWindows?
When I use Aggregation function over SlidingWindow what does flink store in state?
For example, if I aggregate count over sliding window with size 1 hour, and slide of 5 minutes. Does it mean that flink stores 12 counts (long) for every key, or it stores every window slide separately, 12 windows of key and 1 count (long) for every key?
And what if I compute multiple windows? For example 1h, 3h, 6h

Each of the 12 overlapping slides is a separate window with its own per-key state. Similarly, if you have multiple windows of various durations, they all have state that is managed independently.
